# Django: How to redirect with arguments

Tags: python, django

After submit a form, I want to redirect to an specific view passing one flag=True in order to activate a popup like:

```
def view1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('new_view') # Here I need to send flag=True
    else:
        form = Form()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why haven't you accepted an answer?

Answer (score 6):

It's not quite clear on what you mean by arguments if it should be in the query string or arguments to a view.

Either way, below is both solutions;

[redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) accepts args and kwargs

```
redirect('new_view', flag='show') # This is the argument of a view
```

or

```
redirect('{}?flag=True'.format(reverse('new_view'))
```

Then you can access it in the view like so

```
show_flag = bool(request.GET.get('flag', False))
```

Comment: Will this work if url doesn't accept arguments?
I mean an url like: url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='new_view')

Comment: No, you'd have to use the query string approach then. I've updated the answer with how-to.

Answer (score 3):

for a given url pattern such as

`url(r'^random/(?P<arg1>[0-9]+)/(?P<arg2>[0-9]+)/$', views.random, name="urlname")`

or

`url(r'^argfree/', views.random2, name="urlname2`

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def view(request):
    # do your thing
    if something:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("urlname", args=["this_is_arg1", "this_is_arg2"]))
    else:
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("urlname"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [django-url-params](https://github.com/gkrsman/django-url-params) module to help you in this situation. Just add

```
request.cparam = {'flag': True}
return param_redirect(request, viewname)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.urls import reverse

response = redirect(f"{reverse('search')}?query='How to redirect with arguments'")
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers without a textual explanation.