# How do I process in Django a text submit with "Post" or "GET" method from HTML?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a project to build a Wiki page in Django and I require to process a word sent from a search field and display its information on screen in case the word matches the stored information. For this I want to send a parameter with "POST" method from the following html template.

```
<form action="{% url 'wiki:index' %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
                    
          <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">                    
          <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The idea is for the parameter to be received by the following functions of my file views.py written in Django.

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":        
        title = request.POST["q"]
        return redirect("wiki:languages")
        
    else:    
           
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entries": util.list_entries()
        })

def languages(request, title):
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/definitions.html", {
        "title": util.get_entry(title)            
    })
```

This file has the next header sentences:

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

from . import util
```

The "Languages" function in turn processes the get_entry(title) function of the "util.py" code

```
def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

I have the following paths indicated in the file "urls.py"

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.languages, name="languages"),
]
```

This is intended to display the contents of the "file. md" found within the "entries" directory and whose name matches the text typed in the search field of the html template. In doing so, however, it displays the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'languages' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'languages' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']
```

I tried to use the parameter "form" but maybe I didn’t know how to use it and I didn’t achieve the goal.
I hope you can help me modify my functions in Django and html to properly use the function "get_entry(title)" and display the contents of the file ".md" that matches the information typed.

Comment: since you specified name="languages" in the path, check the main urls.py and see if you have setup app_name in your project, and check if you can access using app_name.url_name like if your app name is app1, then see if you can access app1.languages.

Comment: I confirm that the file "urls.py" contains the app name **"app_name = "wiki"**. As for your suggestion, I don’t know if I understood or did it wrong but the connection is rejected. In the main "urls.py" file I added the line: **path(' ', include("app1.urls"))** and from the index function, I modified the redirect to the "languages" function as follows: **return redirect("app1.languages")** but the connection is rejected. Please confirm if this is what you suggested or you’d better try something else.

Comment: return redirect("wiki:languages") here you are doing a normal  redirect and languages is expecting a call to languages url with a parameter. Try doing a redirect by passing the obtained input from post as parameter to the url. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that’s what’s missing, but I didn’t know how to send that parameter. I tried from the html template, sending the parameter "q" as follows: **<form action="{% url 'wiki:index' q %}" method="post">** And within the function of Django I have:                            
**title = request.POST["q"]** But the error is always the same.

Comment: I read that from the html template it is necessary to send the parameter in the following way (word1.word2), e.g.: person.id, or that it should be something like the following:
**<form action="{% url 'wiki:index' word1.word2 %}" method="post">** Do you know how to build that parameter or if It's necessary something additional in the Django code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972160/django-how-to-redirect-with-arguments#48972207 Take a look at this.